# Serve react app with different static prefix in dev mode

Tags: reactjs, npm, static-files, npm-start

I am running a react app with npm and would like to modify the path for the static files.

I modified the package.json to include `"homepage": "./app"`.

As expected the files are now served at .../app/static when I use a production build with `npm run build`, but I cannot replicate this behavior with the development server (`npm start`).

How can I make the dev server serve at `/app/static` as well?

Thanks for any suggestions.